# Тип для функции объект массивов в массив объектов с ключом из объекта в начале

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript, объекты, typescript-типы

Есть функция на js.

```js
export function aggregatedArrays2ObjectArray(schoolsData) {
  const entries = Object.entries(schoolsData);

  if (!entries || !entries[0] || !entries[1].length) return [];
  return entries[0][1].map((_, index) => {
    const dataToReturn = {};

    entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      dataToReturn[key] = value[index];
    });

    return dataToReturn;
  });
}
```

Эта функция делает из объекта

```js
{
  name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
  otherkey: ['otherkey1', 'otherkey2', 'otherkey3']
}
```

В массив объектов

```js
[
  {
    name: 'name1',
    otherkey: 'otherkey1'
  }, {
    name: 'name2',
    otherkey: 'otherkey2'
  }, {
    name: 'name3',
    otherkey: 'otherkey3'
  }
]
```

Нужно продумать верный тип для этой функции на typescript
Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться

Спасибо

Comment: а что мещает просто описать `{name: string, otherKey: string}[]?`

Comment: Эта функция используется каждый раз для разных объектов

Comment: https://clck.ru/SYiF3 например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [так](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAgg5nAThOBDYEAmNGNSAZwCYB5AIwCsIBjYHPEAJQgIFcAbYAHgBUA%20KAF4oAbwCwAKChQA2gGkoASwB2UANYQQAewBmUHgF0AXFALBEKuJIC%20kyTtbLairatQJkaDNlz5i5Klp6fF4%20AAoCagALLS12AgARdFQTHgBKE3gkFHQsYMJSSho6XyYWDm5%20GQNRSWlqVzMoCGVzRRYhKADigDoWtpYI6Nj4pOBUNIBuOyklPTCAQn6LDoAfVagl1pWCGQAGGvXN5fbdgEYDHvYWuGAotKhkYFZEVWrp2aeX1ROWfYMZBcegBbVBgMJhAD6JlQyhAABolMpMBAAB4mZSsYFkCCIB6CATiWb1RrAKCYZI8LTMZ6vEzMBqITBcMwWZRwRGsywCYQiawfOrSZrbU49HRaRAAUVQ0QhMg0CKgADdUOxWBADPjCYKheTKdSILTlPLNDVhCq1RAZCoUaiDB9ddYpjNdV9XnrxlSad8HVAnR9bBJJCoMIgdDLoABlYZxRLJWqzZSoYEQExc9nvQVaO64hVptoZ%2002GYNZRNCnjEzRmKxsaoTpE6RJlMmGQAcmbEDObcRHeTECIPagfZTAGY2wZ4Vmc4g87I29mornNN3e4vlyBB2uZwrx5Pi0GJKWmsg2JxOu5sl48qV-EUgqUuNWRnHxuEKxMPqeKv8euvZ5okxQAA9MBXRyJI36cL%20BBaCmIFgQAciQPDgVAQA)

```
type AggregatedArrays2ObjectArrayResult<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string
}

function aggregatedArrays2ObjectArray<T>(schoolsData: T): AggregatedArrays2ObjectArrayResult<T>[] {
  const entries = Object.entries(schoolsData);

  if (!entries || !entries[0] || !entries[1].length) return [];
  return entries[0][1].map((_: any, index: number) => {
    const dataToReturn: Record<string, string> = {};

    entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
      dataToReturn[key] = value[index];
    });

    return dataToReturn;
  });
}

interface SchoolsData {
  name: string[];
  otherkey: string[];
}

const data: SchoolsData = {
  name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
  otherkey: ['otherkey1', 'otherkey2', 'otherkey3'],
}

const result = aggregatedArrays2ObjectArray<SchoolsData>(data);
result[0].otherkey; // OK
result[0].some // NOT OK
```

`[K in keyof T]` - запись означает *"Взять все ключи из типа T и использовать их, как ключи для нового типа"*.

[Подробнее](https://medium.com/@lopatsin1990/typescript-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-keyof-%D0%B8-in-key-in-586ebe8e6460)

Comment: `<SchoolsData>(data)` - redundant

Answer (score 0):

```
type base = { [k: string]: any[] };
type convertedList<T extends base> = { [k in keyof T]: T[k][0] }[];

declare function convert<T extends base>(base: T): convertedList<T>;
```

```
t1: {
    let arr = convert({
        name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
        otherkey: [1, 2, 3]
    })
    const {
        // const name: string
        name,
        // const otherkey: number
        otherkey
    } = arr[0]
}
```

```
t2: {
    let arr: convertedList<{ name: string[], otherkey: number[] }> = [
        {
            name: '',
            // otherkey: 'str' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.(2322)
            otherkey: 1
        }, {
            name: '',
            otherkey: 3
        }
    ]
}
```

```
t3: {
    const base = { otherkey: [1, '2', [3]] }
    let arr: convertedList<typeof base> = [
        {
            // (property) otherkey: string | number | number[]
            otherkey: 1
        }
    ]
}
```